# What will happen if I place a neutral conducting sheet in front of a charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Let's say I put a neutral conducting sheet in front of a charge. What will happen to the sheet?

If I place a plate with some thickness in front of the charge, charges will develop on the face of the plate to maintain the electric field inside the plate zero.

There is no such thing inside the sheet, so how will it react to the charge in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have a similar effect in the area; the charge carriers in the shet will arange in a way to minimize the resulting field gradient, which will result in a circular change in charge density. This also happens on the surface of the plate but is spear over a larger area and thus often neglected.